# How does a goliath level up?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am trying to get the achievement to let a goliath level up four times before killing him, but how does a goliath level up? I have leveled up four times already and I can't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shoot a goliath's helmet off to anger him and immediately he will begin attacking the closest enemy near him to level himself up, even his allies. Goliaths require more enemies to kill to progress to the next level as they become stronger. When they level up, they deal increased damage and replenish their health.

Aside from the achievement, the beneficial aspects of allowing a goliath to level is that their dropped loot will be more valuable and the experience from the enemies they killed is tripled and added to their own.

Comment: +1 did not know about the XP being tripled and added. I usually took them out fairly early!